# Edit Label in TreeCtrl only on double click event of the items

Tags: mfc

In tree control, I want to edit labels only when double clicking the item text. I don't want to edit the label on single click on the item text.

How to achieve it?

I tried below code but in-place edit control is never getting display.

```
 void CMyTreeCtrl::OnNMDblclkTree1( NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult )
    {
       CPoint p;
       GetCursorPos( &p );
       ScreenToClient( &p );
       HTREEITEM h = HitTest( p );
       if( h )
       {
          if(EndEditLabelNow( FALSE ) )
          {
            SelectItem( h );
             EditLabel( h );
          }
       }

    void CMyTreeCtrl::OnTvnBeginlabeleditTree1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
    {
        LPNMTVDISPINFO pTVDispInfo = reinterpret_cast<LPNMTVDISPINFO>(pNMHDR);
        if ( !m_bEditLabel)
            *pResult = 1;
        else
            *pResult = 0;
    }

    void CMyTreeCtrl::OnEndLabelEdit(LPNMHDR pnmhdr, LRESULT *pLResult)
    {
        TV_DISPINFO     *ptvinfo;
        ptvinfo = (TV_DISPINFO *)pnmhdr;
        if (ptvinfo->item.pszText != NULL)
        {
            ptvinfo->item.mask = TVIF_TEXT;
            SetItem(&ptvinfo->item);
        }
        *pLResult = 0;
        m_bEditLabel = false;
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Instead cal EditLabel( h );, try to send OnTvnBeginlabeleditTree1 message to the tree.

Comment: @flaviu2 I tried with SendMessage(TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT,0,0); still in-place edit control is not getting displayed.In OnEndLabelEdit I am getting NULL for  ptvinfo->item.pszText wheras in OnTvnBeginlabeleditTree1 I am getting correct value for pTVDispInfo ->item.pszText.

Comment: Sending SendMessage(TVN_BEGINLABELEDIT,0,0); is ok ? I don't think you should send 0, 0  as second and third parameter ...

Comment: Or, try something like this: PostMessage (TVM_EDITLABEL, 0, hTreeItem);, where hTreeItem is the handle of the tree item that you want to edit ...

Comment: Or, you can try this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e705x0t.aspx

Comment: Can’t you derive your own class from the base class and override the notification and suppress the base from being executed? Just a guess.